# DDD - how to write good, robust code using a basic example

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

For a new application, I'm using layers :

RestRessource -> ApplicationService -> Domain

I have a basic use case where the user can create an"bduget". If no other budget exists for the current year, the status is 'INITIAL'. AFter that a new budget can be created and its status will be 'CORRECTIVE' coupled to another attribute 'index' : CORRECTIVE#1, CORRECTIVE#2, ...

Now some coding. 
The ApplicationService has a methode called "createBudget"

```
@Autowired
private BudgetRepository budgetRepo;

@Autowired
private BudgetService budgetService;

public Budget createBudget(int year) {
    Budget newBudget;
    if (budgetService.existsBudgetInitialFor(year)) {
        newBudget = new Budget(year, "INITIAL");
    } else {
        newBudget = new Budget(year, "CORRECTIVE", budgetService.nextIndex());
    }
    budgetRepo.insert(newBudget);
    return newBudget;
}
```

BudgetService is using BudgetRepository to make a database count.
existsBudgetInitialFor returns a boolean if count > 0 :)

And now the questions :

1. For this example, I find budgetServcie useless. Is it better to move existsBudgetInitialFor inside BudgetRepository ?
2. Do you think the "if ... else ..." statement is at the good place : is it AppService layer responsibility or for you, it is a domain rule and to enforce this, do you move this code inside BudgetService ?
3. To encapsulate the budgetService.nextIndex call, is it better to sue a factory for creating Budget ? (in place of the constructor). And do you think it is the right time to compute the nextIndex.
4. The application layer is subjet to unit test or perhaps only to integration test ? Why do you ask that for ? When I tried to unit test this methode I needed to mock at least BudgetService, BudgetRepository, I was thinking : is it a sign of code smell ? Another solution to ease unit test is to extract `budgetService.existsBudgetInitialFor(year)` as a private method, mock it to returns TRUE / FALSE as I wish etc.
5. I didn't think when writing this code that the creation is the responsibility of the entity. I found awkard to put the "if... else ..." logic inside Budget entity. Am I right ? (please tell me I'm right at least once :D)
6. And a last question I was asking myself : perhaps I was wrong from the start. Is it better if the UI send a `createInitialBudget` command and then a `createCorrectiveBudget` command ? In this case We need to check the command validity (to avoid multiple initial creation : uniquess validation).

It's only a very simple code (I put aside rights management, validation, etc). So I try to make this kind of code right before coding more complexe usecases. The main purpose is validating the layers, explains it to my colleagues, show that this code can be tested, etc.

Thanks a lot !

François

Comment: Also watch out for concurrency conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

1. Your application service seems to have business logic.  If that's the case it belongs in a domain service.  The application service would then just called domainBudgetService.CreateBudget(int year) as you have it now.  You can move existsBudgetInitialFor to a repository if you want.
2. See #1
3. Yes factory would be preferred.
4. If you move budgetservice method to the repository then I don't think this is an issue.  I usually only unit test my domain services and entities.
5. A factory should take away this awkwardness
6. I would simply have one createBudget command and keep the logic internally like you have it.  Otherwise the UI now needs to have business logic to determine what kind of command to send.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is an implementation concern that belongs to the Budget itself and its knowledge about how to name a certain status:

a) the domain service:

```
numberOfBudgets = budgetRepository.numberOfBudgetsIn(anYear);
budget = Budget.newFrom(anYear, numberOfBudgets + 1);
budgetRepository.add(budget);
```

b) the public factory method within the Budget class:

```
Budget.newFrom(anYear, budgetNumber) {
  status = 'INITIAL';
  if (numberOfBudgets > 0) {
    status = 'CORRECTIVE' + budgetNumber
  }
  return new Budget(anYear, status);
}
```

This way you only have one domain service mentioned in point a.

Cheers,
Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

> For this example, I find budgetServcie useless. Is it better to move
>   existsBudgetInitialFor inside BudgetRepository ?

Good idea I say, personally I don't like xxxService(xxx is the entity name), the name itself does not show much meaning.

> Do you think the "if ... else ..." statement is at the good place : is
>   it AppService layer responsibility or for you, it is a domain rule and
>   to enforce this, do you move this code inside BudgetService ?

In this use case, I think it is acceptable to leave the statement in the application service. As the unit test remains simple with two alternative paths(initial and budget exists). If the use case grows more complex or some other use case involves Budget creation, maybe you need a BudgetFactory to hold the statement.

> To encapsulate the budgetService.nextIndex call, is it better to sue a
>   factory for creating Budget ? (in place of the constructor). And do
>   you think it is the right time to compute the nextIndex.

Yes, I think it's the right time. If it is not computed here, it is likely it will be computed in persistence layer which is more difficult to test as they usually takes more effort to write and maintain and are more fragile.

> The application layer is subjet to unit test or perhaps only to
>   integration test ? Why do you ask that for ? When I tried to unit test
>   this methode I needed to mock at least BudgetService,
>   BudgetRepository, I was thinking : is it a sign of code smell ?
>   Another solution to ease unit test is to extract
>   budgetService.existsBudgetInitialFor(year) as a private method, mock
>   it to returns TRUE / FALSE as I wish etc.

Considering the simplicity of this use case, do unit test if you leave the if-else statement in the application layer. If you introduce a BudgetFactory to encapsulate the if-else and nextIndex, the application layer becomes a thin one. You could still write unit test if you adopt tdd, if not, it is also ok to leave it covered by the functional test.

> I didn't think when writing this code that the creation is the
>   responsibility of the entity. I found awkard to put the "if... else
>   ..." logic inside Budget entity. Am I right ? (please tell me I'm
>   right at least once :D)
>   I agree. A single budget cannot tell whether there is other budgets exists.
>
> And a last question I was asking myself : perhaps I was wrong from the
>   start. Is it better if the UI send a createInitialBudget command and
>   then a createCorrectiveBudget command ? In this case We need to check
>   the command validity (to avoid multiple initial creation : uniquess
>   validation).

I don't think it's a good idea when the UI shows two button with createCorrectiveBudget and createInitialBudget and let the user choose which one he/she should click. The validation on the backend is good but the knowledge leaks, it forces people to make unnecessary choice.